# Etymology of Borborygmos?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Recently found out that the word "borborygmus" exists (a rumbling or gurgling noise made by the movement of fluid and gas in the intestines), and my immediate thought was of [Borborygmos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=460299), the Gruul legend. I'm assuming that there's just about zero chance that the etymology of Borborygmos has nothing to do with borborygmus, but I'm curious as to how the legend/giant himself has anything to do with intestinal gastric gurgling. Any insights as to the etymology/connection there?

Answer (score 3):

This is speculation, but Borborygmos has a heavy flavor angle of the barbarian trope of fighting and feasting.  The flavor text on the original printing of Borborygmos references the only other two cards in the original Ravnica block referencing Borborygmos, Wreak Havoc (where he is quoted saying, "Crush Them!") and Protean Hulk (where he is quoted saying, "Meat and eggs.  We eat!").  What better name for him than the rumbling of the intestines?  It combines his two obsessions of brawling and eating.

See the flavor text on the following three cards:

[image: Borborygmos]

[image: Protean Hulk]

[image: Wreak Havoc]

Answer (score 0):

In the book D&D Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica the following is mentioned about him...

> He embodied the raging fire that the Gruul believe burns in their
> bellies, and his wrath toward the civilization of Ravnica knew no
> bounds.